# Excluding Certain Matching Rows in an SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

My issue somewhat complex, so I will explain using simplified versions of my tables.

This is Table 1:

```
Value L  AID      OID
A        1         1
B        2         1
C        3         1
D        4         1
E        2         1
F        2         2
G        2         3
H        2         4
```

This is Table 2:

```
Value R  AID    OID    VAR
Z        0      1      0
Y        1      1      1
X        2      1      1
W        4      1      1
V        0      2      0
U        1      2      1
T        3      2      1
```

I would like to join these tables such that any row in Table 1 that doesn’t have a corresponding row in Table 2 with both matching AID and OID is returned in a join to the row with a matching OID and an AID and VAR of 0. In this example it would look like this:

```
Value L   Value R   AID   OID   VAR
C         Z         3     1     0
F         V         2     2     0
H         V         4     2     0
```

I am not certain how to tackle this. Specifically, not sure how to stop the rows that have a matching AID and OID from showing up in my join, and only having the rows that don't have that match. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears in your example you would like missing records from table 1 joined to the closet match in table 2 (by way of OID) with a var = 0.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.aid = t1.aid and t2.oid = t1.oid and t2.var = 0
                 );
```

Comment: I had tried NOT EXISTS. That still gives me all of the values, not just the ones that don't have a corresponding AID.

Comment: @adunn . . . You might need the `var` comparison as well.  Your question is not consistent on whether you want the `var` to be included in the matching logic.